# In need of an example of RpcDispatcher for remote method invocation

Tags: java, methods, call, jgroups

I am writing a Java application which will be using Jgroups. I have downloaded the JGroups jar and everything looks good from a basic functionality standpoint. I am able to create a simple cluster, and then lanch multiple java JVMS/nodes via JChannel calls in other Java programs which connect/join the cluster just fine. However, I can't seem to get callRemoteMethods to work. Here's the deal. I have the master Java application which I want to start in a JVM that gets launched by the java command. I then would like to have that master Java app launch another JVM via jgroups and start a method which is coded in my master Java application in this second JVM. The example in the Jgroup manual is not that good, and unfortunately examples online are scarce.

Any examples would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

--Justin

Answer (score 1):

JGroups comes with plenty of tests that show how to use RpcDispatcher, e.g.
- https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/blob/master/tests/junit/org/jgroups/blocks/RpcDispatcherUnitTest.java
- https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/blob/master/tests/junit/org/jgroups/blocks/RpcDispatcherTest.java

The manual also shows an example at http://www.jgroups.org/manual-3.x/html/user-building-blocks.html#RpcDispatcher

Comment: Thank you soo much, that got it going. One last question, hopefully. I have two windows open one running the server we'll call it, and the other running the client. The client is calling a method, which just does a, system.out.println("Hello from method1");, which is coded on the server, however the server's jgroup console is the one displaying the output. The server window does not display the message when the client does not remote call that method. I expected to see the system.println message in the client window when the client called it.